# How to model "time-to-adopt"

Tags: survival, hazard

I have data of many users (several millions) and the timing of when each of then has adopted a product. All of then have adopted so it is not a matter of the propensity to adopt - in their case they all adopted in 100%. BUT - the users are divided into 3 subgroups and I want to test whether one subgroup members adopt products earlier than the other subgroup users. Are hazard models suitable here? I'm not sure as all of the cases have the same outcome (they all adopt), and it's just a question of timing.... In addition, I might have several adoption cases for each user - how should I handle them?
I would really appreciate any help with deciding what is the best model for my problem... Thanks!

Comment: Yes they are appropriate. I think discrete survival models are easy to understand : the standard is logistic regression on survival with time as independent variable. So you are predicting probability of adoption in each time period.

Comment: @seanv507 good point. If anything, survival models are perfect here. If everyone adopts _eventually_, that's analogous to every study participant dying _eventually_.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! But how should I control for each individual? I mean - I may have users who adopt multiple products and I want to control for their individual attributes